# How to use nagios to monitor a pfServer server?

Tags: networking, monitoring

I have a pfSense server set up as firewall gateway for my lab lan and dmz. Now I installed Nagios monitoring manager on a Linux server in lan and want to add a host target for the pfSense firewall. Could someone give any idea for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Click on Services->SNMP, enable the SNMP server, set a community string, and Bob's your uncle. You can check whether it works or not.

Comment: We do this at work using Observium. It does a fairly good job out of the box to monitor everything.